# Нужны ли кавычки для небесных львов?

Tags: пунктуация

Китайских собачек Фу еще называют небесными львами Будды. Нужно ли вставлять слова небесные львы в кавычки? И еще, эти слова - небесные львы - писать с большой буквы или с маленькой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Слова *небесные львы* **не нужно** брать в кавычки и писать с заглавной буквы, поскольку они употреблены **не в переносном значении** и это **не имя собственное**.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

**Как-то выделить название всё-таки надо**,  а то будет казаться, что существуют реальные небесные львы, например:

[**Собаки Фу (Fu Dog), Небесные львы Будды, собако-львы и их роль в фэн шуй**](http://igelnik.ru/fudogs/index.php)

Варианты встречаются разные (кавычки, все буквы прописные, все буквы строчные), но наиболее подходяще название –  **Небесные львы Будды.** Это имя собственное, название  талисмана, с прописной буквы пишется первое слово.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол НАЗЫВАЮТ позволяет обойтись без кавычек и прописной буквы. Этот глагол употребляется между основным и неосновным названием предмета, он готовит читателя к восприятию неосновного названия, часто употреблённого в переносном значении (как в Вашем примере),  и дополнительных средств выделения не требуется.

Ср.: На выставке "небесные львы Будды" привлекли всеобщее внимание. (Здесь кавычки нужны, ибо употреблено только второе, неофициальное, название педмета.)

Comment: Без кавычек и прописной буквы пишутся нарицательные имена/названия, в том числе сочетания, давно существующие и понятные носителям языка (не думаю, что небесные львы - это тот самый случай). Но даже и тогда могут существовать разные формы для разных текстов и стилей речи.